# Maven Module with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to configure Maven to use Spring Boot with multi modules, this is my structure:

```
- Parent
------ WebClient
------------ scr/main/java/config ---> Config Files
------------ scr/main/java/resources/WEB-INF ---> Template Files
------ Core
------ Services
------ Server
```

I have a config file where I put my ViewResolver:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

@Bean
public ViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    // View Resolver
    UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Here is my parent pom.xml modules and dependencies:

```
<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>services</module>
    <module>server</module>
    <module>webclient</module>
</modules>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- =========================== Spring ======================= -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security and MVC dependences -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>
```

At my Server's POM file I have this dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>webclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

My SpringBootApplication looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"config"})
public class ServerRunner {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerRunner.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I start my application, I see my mapping working and it seems that everything works well but the problem is that Spring does not find my templates:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/index.jsp
```

What is wrong with my config? Where should I put my template files?
Thanks for your help!

**EDITED:**

If I put my template files at Server Project (server\src\main\webapp) it works! So... How do I make the server to read webclient project templates? I need the templates in that submodule.

**EDITED 2:**
Solved avoid "jsp" files, see answer and comments

Comment: The message you got is warning message. It says that your view renderer encountered an error and triggered a redirection to the default mapping `/error` which is not implemented. The real error is the one that trigger this redirection. give us your log details before this message.

Comment: I don't have any error at my server console: `2016-03-31 11:05:14.562  INFO 8824 --- [main] server.ServerRunner    : Started ServerRunner in 4.628 seconds (JVM running for 5.379)`

Comment: I think that the error it's the `Not Found` printed at the Error Page

Comment: What do you mean with server's pom? Is your server's pom inheriting from the parent POM? As a recommendation, do not use Spring project specific versions when using Boot. Just inherit from Spring Boot's parent pom and leave the version numbers empty, Spring will take care of them.

Comment: Yes, my server's pom inheriting from the parent POM. I'll apply your recomendation.

Comment: Becarful what you are putting in your `webapps` file. `Do not use the src/main/webapp directory if your application will be packaged as a jar. Although this directory is a common standard, it will only work with war packaging and it will be silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.` You can find more information at: `http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content`

Comment: Thanks Drew1208, I'll use 'static' instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to [JSP limitations described in Boot reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) - you can't just read JSPs from anywhere in the classpath (whereas this works with other templating engines).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brian! I didn't know about that limitation. But I think I need something else... if I change my ViewResolver and I try to serve a html template file I get the same error `Not Found: /WEB-INF/index.html`

Comment: could you try with no custom resolver, no custom conf (just a thymeleaf starter and a template in `src/main/resources/templates`? As pointed out by  Drew1208, the webapp location could be a problem

Comment: If i put my template file at `server/src/main/resources/templates` thymeleaf can find it and it works... But if I put the file at `webclient/src/main/resources/templates` is still not working (`template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`) I need my template files at "webclient" project, there's any solution?

Comment: make sure that your client JAR has those templates under the proper location (`classes/templates`?) and that your web project depends on the right version of your client jar (you can `jar -tvf` the client jar contained in your executable jar/war)